# Ember router: how to use transitionTo

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

I have a link that looks like this

```
index.html#/calendar/year/month
```

This is how I set up my routes:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('calendar', {path: 'calendar/:currentYear/:currentMonth'});
});

App.CalendarRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function (params) {
    var obj = {
       weeks: calendar.getDaysInMonth(params.currentMonth, params.currentYear),
       currentMonth: params.currentMonth,
       currentYear: params.currentYear
    };
    return obj;
  },
  setUpController: function(controller, model) {
      controller.set('content', model);
  }
});
```

I can get to it by doing this:

```
var currentMonth = this.get('content.currentMonth');
var nextMonth = parseInt(currentMonth)+1;
var route = '#/calendar/'
var year = this.get('content.currentYear');
window.location.href= route + year + '/' + nextMonth;
```

But I'd like to use the router instead.

I tried:

```
var router = this.get('target');
router.transitionTo('#calendar/'+year + '/' + nextMonth);
```

But I get this error:

> Uncaught Error: assertion failed: The route #calendar/2013/5 was not found

I also tried:

```
var router = this.get('target');
router.transitionTo('calendar/'+year + '/' + nextMonth);
```

But this also gives me an error:

> Uncaught Error: assertion failed: The route calendar/2013/5 was not found

Edit: displaying my routing above

Comment: hmm, in `router.transitionTo('#calendar/'+year + '/' + nextMonth);` you're missing a "/" after the "#". i don't know what else might be wrong, but i usually use something like either `this.transitionToRoute('example.name');` or `App.Router.router.transitionTo('example.name');`.

Comment: That sounds good, so I just tried: router.transitionTo('#/calendar/' + year + '/' + nextMonth); But then I get Uncaught Error: assertion failed: The route #/calendar/2013/5 was not found

Comment: @redconservatory I believe this problem is related to your definition of routes. This should probably be a nested route with a segment for year and another with a segment for month. Also, he way you're currently doing seems to be missing the `params` argument in your `model` method in that route.

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe can you provide a code sample of how to nest with my year and month segment? i.e. is it just like this.route('year', {path: ':currentYear', function() {// my other nested route... }}); ?

Comment: @redconservatory It would be something along these lines. I won't have the time to write it anytime soon, but I'd suggest that you read [this](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/) and [this](http://darthdeus.github.io/blog/2013/02/01/ember-dot-js-router-and-template-naming-convention/). Focus on understanding the `Router.map` and the declaration of `resource` and `route` within it. I'll try to write something later today tho

Comment: @redconservatory got you a code sample, see below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oposite from what I said in the comments, this can actually be done without the need of nested routes, using the [`Route#serialize`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_serialize).

I've made [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/dWpS9/) ([demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/dWpS9/show)) with a scenario similar to what you described:

In the application, I'm storing the month and year arguments

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create({
    title: 'Cool App',
    calendar: { 
        month: new Date().getMonth()+1, 
        year: new Date().getFullYear() 
    }
});
```

Defined the routes

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.route("home");
    this.resource('calendar', { path: 'calendar/:year/:month'});
});
```

In the calendar route, I've added the `serialize` method, to translate the properties in `obj` to the app, then I connected with 3rd party lib in `setupController` to get the `days` property and set its content.

```
App.CalendarRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    activate: function() {
        $(document).attr('title','Events')
    },
    serialize: function(obj) {
        return {
            year: obj.year, month: obj.month
        }
    },
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        var obj = {
            days: calendar.getDaysInMonth(model.month, model.year),
            year: model.year,
            month: model.month
        };
        controller.set('content', obj);
    }
});
```

In Handlebars, using a `{{linkTo}}` helper, I am passing the `calendar` property defined in my `App` class as the argument:

```
{{#linkTo calendar App.calendar tagName="li"}}
    <a {{bindAttr href="view.href"}}>
        Calendar
    </a>
{{/linkTo}}
```

This will generate a link to `~/#/calendar/2013/4`

Comment: Thanks! This is actually a more complete explanation than in the actual documentation. Really helps.

Comment: I feel your pain. The documentation has a few gaps, but I'm sure it will be better soon. If you feel like helping, you should visit the [website repo](https://github.com/emberjs/website/issues). There's lots to be done :)

Answer (score 0):

The router is for more than a url manager.  It manages the state for the entire application.  In order to fully help you it would be better to see more code.  Have you created routes?  Are you just trying to go to a 'url' that is not handled by the ember app?

`this.transistionTo(routeName)` expects to receive a named route as far a I know.  It will then generate the correct url for that route.  If you have not setup any routes then I don't think you are able to use it.

Comment: That gives me "Uncaught More objects were passed than dynamic segments "

Comment: Sorry, looking at the route closer you should just pass the calendar object as it is only expecting one parameter and uses that to create the two parameters