# Creating links from multiple dynamic segments

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to build a blog type application that has URLs that contain both the category and the post (entry) id. For instance, I want a URL to be `/apple/123` or `/basketball/456`.

The technique I've tried so far is found at http://jsbin.com/ogorab/202/edit.

From the index template:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span4">
        {{#each entry in content}}
        <h2>Heading</h2>

         {{#linkTo "entry" entry class="btn" }}{{entry.title}}{{/linkTo}}
        <p></p>
        {{/each}}
    </div>
</div>
```

throws the error:

> Uncaught Error: assertion failed: Cannot call get with 'id' on an undefined object.

This makes sense since the `linkTo` functionality expects to build links from what appears to be only the id parameter, but has no way of specifying additional parameters from which to build a correct URL.

My goal is to build a list of links such that they can each have two dynamic segments.

The closest issue I've found that was logged in ember is [this one](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1334), but no best practice or example was given and the issue was closed.

Is this type of thing possible in Ember? If so, hopefully someone can provide some guidance.

Comment: You have to implement [`Route#serialize`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15925953/ember-router-how-to-use-transitionto/15938988#15938988) if you want to use something other than `id` with `{{linkTo}}`

Comment: Thanks, this was the key I was missing. Do you know what prevents a serialize function for a route associated with an  that passes in an empty model from being fired by Ember when I render a template within its outlet? If not, I'll open another question.