# Ember.js: display items inside an hasMany relationship

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-router

Given these models:

```
App.TransportDocument = DS.Model.extend
  number: DS.attr 'string'
  date: DS.attr 'string'
  printable_url: DS.attr 'string'
  transport_document_rows: DS.hasMany('App.TransportDocumentRow')

App.TransportDocumentRow = DS.Model.extend
  product_name: DS.attr 'string'
  quantity: DS.attr 'number'
  measure: DS.attr 'string'
  transport_document: DS.belongsTo('App.TransportDocument')
```

here are my routes:

```
App.TransportDocumentsRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: -> App.TransportDocument.find()

App.TransportDocumentRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: (params)-> App.TransportDocument.find(params.transport_document_id)

App.TransportDocumentRowRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: -> App.TransportDocumentRow.find()
```

I have an handlebars template:

```
{{#each transport_document in controller}}
  td_id: {{transport_document.id}}
  {{#each transport_document_row in transport_document.transport_document_rows}}
    row_id: {{id}}
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

i expected my result to be:

```
td_id: 1 row_id: 1 row_id: 2 row_id: 3
td_id: 2 row_id: 3 row_id: 4 row_id: 5
td_id: 3 row_id: 8 row_id: 7 row_id: 6
```

but is is:

```
td_id: 1 row_id: row_id: row_id:
td_id: 2 row_id: row_id: row_id:
td_id: 3 row_id: row_id: row_id:
```

here's my server response to /transport_documents

```
{"transport_documents":
  [
    {"id":1,"number":"11","date":"17/04/2013","cause":"Conto lavorazione","transport_document_row_ids":[3,2,1],"transport_document_rows":    
      [
        {"transport_document_row":{"id":3,"transport_document_id":1,"product_name":"suola puzzle verde","quantity":"1","measure":"pz","}},
        {"transport_document_row":{"id":2,"transport_document_id":1,"product_name":"lacci rossi","quantity":"2","measure":"pz"}},
        {"transport_document_row":{"id":1,"transport_document_id":1,"product_name":"Rotolo di tela","quantity":"50","measure":"m"}}
      ]},
    {"id":2,"number":"2","date":"18/04/2013","cause":"Conto lavorazione","transport_document_row_ids":[6,5,4],"transport_document_rows":
      [
        {"transport_document_row":{"id":6,"transport_document_id":2,"product_name":"suola puzzle verde","quantity":"1","measure":"pz"}},
        {"transport_document_row":{"id":5,"transport_document_id":2,"product_name":"lacci rossi","quantity":"2","measure":"pz"}},
        {"transport_document_row":{"id":4,"transport_document_id":2,"product_name":"Rotolo di tela","quantity":"50","measure":"m",}}
      ]},
    {"id":3,"number":"3","date":"19/04/2013","cause":"Conto lavorazione","transport_document_row_ids":[9,8,7],"transport_document_rows":
      [
        {"transport_document_row":{"id":9,"transport_document_id":3,"product_name":"suola puzzle verde","quantity":"1","measure":"pz"}},
        {"transport_document_row":{"id":8,"transport_document_id":3,"product_name":"lacci rossi","quantity":"2","measure":"pz"}},
        {"transport_document_row":{"id":7,"transport_document_id":3,"product_name":"Rotolo di tela","quantity":"50","measure":"m"}}]}
```

i guess i'm doing something wrong in the routes (where do i define the query to find all the rows of THAT document?) but i'm not sure. Can't find anything like that in the guides

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per convention, the default code in [`Route#serialize`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_serialize) will return an object containing the model id, however the property name is not `id`, but rather the combination of the model name and id, which in your case, should be `transport_document_id`.

The object returned by the `serialize` method will be passed as argument to [`Route#model`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_model). This is also explained in the [routing guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/specifying-a-routes-model/#toc_dynamic-models).

Your route should be something similar to the following:

```
App.TransportDocumentRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: (params)-> 
    App.TransportDocument.find(params.transport_document_id)
```

or you can override the `serialize` of your route to provide a different parameter name.
You can find an example of a different implementation for serialize [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15925953/ember-router-how-to-use-transitionto/15938988#15938988).

---

As for querying, you can filter similarly to the following:

```
App.TransportDocumentRowRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: (params) -> App.store.filter App.TransportDocumentRow, (row) ->
    # might have to implement Route#serialize to also provide the 
    # transport_document_id property in this route
    row.get 'transport_document_id' == params.transport_document_id
```

However, this would only filter the records you have in store. If the row records are not already fetched, you'll also have to fire a GET to fetch them.

btw, sorry if the syntax is not 100%. I don't really speak coffee :)

Comment: - first part of answer: i do have the route defined in that way. I do have the details of my object (but no queries are triggered. Is it expected they are? when i get the /index json it has all the attributes already)
-second part of answer: how do i fire the GET?

Comment: i explain better: when i navigate to `transport_documents` there's an ajax call  that returns all my redords correctly. From there, when i navigate to `transport_documents/1` no queries are done. Maybe the problem is here?

Comment: i'll make a question for it, it's an atomic question and could be useful to other people, cause i can't find similar questions anywhere

Comment: `DS.Model#find` fires a GET. As for these questions, I'd need to see more code to comment on.

Comment: I corrected the first part as you said: you were right and now it's ok. for the second part: I think I have my records in the store (as you can see from the response). Maybe i'm doing it in the wrong way?