# How can I set a link to route with a dynamic segment

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

How can I set a link to route with a dynamic segment. According to guide I start with this

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create()
App.Router.map ->
  @resource 'products'
  @resource 'product', path: '/product/:product_id'
```

in my template:

```
{{#linkTo "product.1"}}products{{/linkTo}}
```

Unfortunately this gives me the follwing error:

```
Uncaught Error: assertion failed: The attempt to linkTo route 'product.1' failed. 
The router did not find 'product.1' in its possible routes: 'products', 'product', 'index'
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`{{linkTo}}`](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.0.0-rc.3/packages/ember-routing/lib/helpers/link_to.js#L257) expects the route defined in the `Router.map`, so in according to your mapping it should be simply `product`.

As for the dynamic segment, you also have to pass an object which will be serialized in the `ProductRoute`. The serialization in almost all scenarios occur without the developer having to do anything since Ember relies on conventions. In rare cases, one must implement `serialize` a [little differently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15925953/ember-router-how-to-use-transitionto/15938988#15938988), but for most cases you don't have to touch it.

If you're using `{{linkTo}}` inside an `{{each}}` loop you can do it like this:

```
{{#each product in controller}}
    {{#linkTo product product}}Details{{/linkTo}}
{{/each}}
```

or

```
{{#each controller}}
    {{#linkTo product this}}Details{{/linkTo}}
{{/each}}
```

Where the first argument is the route name and the second is your model object. In the first code the object has been also named as `product`, while in the second it's simply being passed as `this`, which is the product of the iteration.

If you have an unusual scenario where you have to link to a dynamic route while not using the `{{each}}` loop, you have to expose the object in the `controller` (preferred) or `view`. Then you'd have to do something similar to the following:

```
App.SomeController = Em.Controller.extend
  product: null

App.SomeRoute = Em.Route.extend
  ### 
  controller is actually `SomeController` here
  model is not being used, and is null, while the actual model being
  supplied to the controller is `product`, retrieved from store
  ###
  setupController: (controller, model) ->
    product = App.Product.find 1
    controller.set 'product', product
    return
```

While your template would be similar to this:

```
{{#linkTo product controller.product}}Product{{/linkTo}}
```

***How does the route know the id?***

[Conventions](http://emberjs.com/guides/concepts/naming-conventions/#toc_dynamic-segments). The route will [`serialize`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_serialize) the object you pass, and expose an object with a single property, which has the name of the model for that route, followed be "_id", which in this case would be `product_id`, so when you click that link, the app activates the `ProductRoute`, runs the serialize method creating that id property, which will subsequently be used as the argument of the [`model`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_model) hook. That's where you call `find` passing `params.product_id` as argument. Then the model returns a promise of that model which will be used by the [`setupController`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_setupController), exposing the object to the view layer as `controller.content` or simply `controller`.

Comment: In the `#each`-loop i had to quote `product`: `{{#linkTo 'product' this}}Details{{/linkTo}}`.