# EmberJS - Routing with one optional param?

Tags: ember.js, routes, ember-router

I would like to add a filter param (:date) in the url, but it should not be neccessary.

What doesn't works:

```
this.route("test", {path: "/test/:test_id"});
this.route("test", {path: "/test/:test_id/:date"});
```

But its important that i have only 1  route where i handle it.

```
App.TestRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    if(params.date === undefined) console.log("DATE NOT SET");
    else console.log("DATE SET");
  }
});
```

I hope that somebody knows a solution for this.

Comment: take a look in [`serialize`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_serialize) or take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15925953/ember-router-how-to-use-transitionto/15938988#15938988) or [here](http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/dDWdv/). These samples are using an older version of Ember, but it shows you what you can do in order to properly set a `date` property in `params`, sort of.